# File is not creating slf4j

Tags: java, slf4j

I wanted to have the logging details in my file as defined. But the file is not created,
My logback.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>C:\temp\sanja.log</file>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

  </root>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be a permission issue perhaps?

Comment: SLF4J alone won't log anything. It's an API and you need an implementation in order to log something.

Comment: I use logback implementation. I have defined the dependency in maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  figured it out with some searching in google.

I need to skip jboss default logging in order to allow my logger work correctly.(whatever logback or log4j..etc)

I can skip this by adding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

in jboss-deployment-structure.xml and placed it in web-inf folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html):

> On the MS Windows platform users frequently forget to escape back
>   slashes. For example, the value `c:\temp\test.log` is not likely to be
>   interpreted properly as `'\t'` is an escape sequence interpreted as a
>   single tab character (`\u0009`). Correct values can be specified as
>   `c:/temp/test.log` or alternatively as `c:\\temp\\test.log`. The File
>   option has no default value.

Not 100% sure this applies to XML configuration, but you should try to change your file definition to `<file>C:/temp/sanja.log</file>`.

Comment: I change that, but still no result. :(